# Laplace - Beltrami eigen problem in 1D Riemannian manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry, laplacian, eigenfunctions

Consider a 1D  Riemannian manifold defined on the unit segment $[0,1]$ and equipped with an **unknown** metric $g=g(x)$ which is positive for all $x$.

In this case the Laplace-Beltrami operator $\Delta f= \frac{1}{\sqrt{|G|}} \sum_{i} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}(\sqrt{|G|} \sum_{j} g^{ij} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j})$

(where $G$ is the metric tensor, $g^{ij}$ is its inverse and $f=f(x)$)

reduces to $\Delta f= g^{-1/2} \frac{d}{dx}(g^{-1/2} \frac{df}{dx})=\frac{1}{g}\frac{d^2f}{dx^2}-\frac{1}{2g^2}\frac{dg}{dx}\frac{df}{dx}$

Which boundary conditions on **$f$ and $g$** do I need to solve the eigenproblem
$\Delta f+\lambda f= \frac{1}{g}\frac{d^2f}{dx^2}-\frac{1}{2g^2}\frac{dg}{dx}\frac{df}{dx}+\lambda f= 0$ in this case?

Comment: There are no boundary conditions for $g$. The boundary conditions of $f$ should be chosen by you.

Comment: @Mason And these also determines the metric, g? It still looks to me like one equation with two unknown functions, what am I missing here?

Comment: I interpret it as the metric $g$ is known but arbitrary, and you are solving for eigenfunctions $f$. The metric can be any smooth positive function on $[0, 1]$, and then the valid $f$s are the eigenfunctions of $\Delta_g$, with boundary conditions that you have to specify

Comment: @Mason thanks , now it makes sense..